# How to popup usercontrol on button click action in my case using mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel

I have a situation that i have a window and i have created checkboxes on this window (Number of checkboxes were dynamically decided, i am using using MVVM without using any inbuilt framework like MVVM-Light or PRISM) and after selection of those check boxes i click a button, this button also exist on same window. On click to this button must popup another window (lets say GraphDisplay.xaml which is **UserControl**). But this GraphDisplay will display some graph based on the checkBox-selection done in previous Window.

I also have to pass the selected checkBox information to the GraphDisplay. For example if i checked 2nd and 5th checkbox it may send a variable of type string "2,5" (like in the given format in messagebox http://prntscr.com/dh9u2s). So that GraphDisplay will display graph for 2nd and 5th points only (like this http://prntscr.com/dhakx4)

My button event in Main View Model is like this:

```
  public void MyAction()
        {
            string selectedCheckBoxes = verifyHowManyChecked(); //selectedCheckBoxes gives all the selcted checkboxes
            //appended by ","
            GraphDisplay gd = new GraphDisplay(selectedCheckBoxes); //I want to pass here the selcted values so that i can reuse it there decoding
            //them to get the selcted checkboxes
          // gd.Show() which will not work for sure because its not winform. So

        }
```

MainWindow.Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicCheckBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllActivities}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <CheckBox Background="Gray" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Plot" Height="20" Width="100" Command="{Binding PlotButton}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

GraphDisplay.xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DynamicCheckBox.GraphDisplay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="plotter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <!--<d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
                <d3:HorizontalDateTimeAxis Name="dateAxis"/>
            </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>-->
            <d3:Header FontFamily="Georgia" Content="Voltage chart"/>
            <d3:VerticalAxisTitle FontFamily="Georgia" Content="Voltage [V]" />
            <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle FontFamily="Georgia" Content="Time"/>
            <d3:HorizontalLine Value="{Binding MaxVoltage}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>
            <d3:HorizontalLine Value="{Binding MinVoltage}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

GraphDisplay.xaml.cs is:

```
 public partial class GraphDisplay : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<double> points_x_y_Graph1 = new List<double>() { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 };
        List<double> points_x_y_Graph2 = new List<double>() { 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 };
        private int _maxVoltage; private int _minVoltage;
    public int MaxVoltage
    {
        get { return _maxVoltage; }
        set { _maxVoltage = value; OnPropertyChanged("MaxVoltage"); }
    }
    public int MinVoltage
    {
        get { return _minVoltage; }
        set { _minVoltage = value; OnPropertyChanged("MinVoltage"); }
    }

    public VoltagePointCollection voltagePointCollection1;
    public VoltagePointCollection voltagePointCollection2;
    DispatcherTimer updateCollectionTimer;
    private int i = 0;
    public GraphDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        updateCollectionTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        updateCollectionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        updateCollectionTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(updateCollectionTimer_Tick);
        updateCollectionTimer.Start();

        voltagePointCollection1 = new VoltagePointCollection();
        var ds1 = new EnumerableDataSource<VoltagePoint>(voltagePointCollection1);
        ds1.SetXMapping(x => x.time);
        ds1.SetYMapping(y => y.Voltage);

        plotter.AddLineGraph(ds1, Colors.Green, 2, "Volts 1");
        MaxVoltage = 1;
        MinVoltage = -1;

        voltagePointCollection2 = new VoltagePointCollection();
        var ds2 = new EnumerableDataSource<VoltagePoint>(voltagePointCollection2);
        ds2.SetXMapping(x => x.time);
        ds2.SetYMapping(y => y.Voltage);

        plotter.AddLineGraph(ds2, Colors.Blue, 2, "Volts 2");
    }
    void updateCollectionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i < points_x_y_Graph1.Count)
        {
            //{ i = 0; }
            //For first graph
            voltagePointCollection1.Add(new VoltagePoint(points_x_y_Graph1[i], i));
            //For second graph
            voltagePointCollection2.Add(new VoltagePoint(points_x_y_Graph2[i], i)); // To add one more graph
            i++;
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**How to Pop-Up Usercontrol on the MyAction() invoke. And How to pass the selected checkboxes to the GraphDisplay usercontrol so that it will display the selected checkboxes Graph using MVVM ?**

Comment: Are you using any framework (Prism, MvvmLight) for this?

Comment: No, I am not using any framework for MVVM.. Its just manual implementation of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your graph control to the MainWindow.xaml and bind it's visibility to a property on your VM (e.g. IsShowingGraph) using a bool to visibility converter if need be.

Button click would then update the IsShowingGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But the idea is also to know how such situation is generally handled in WPF ?

Comment: Ok, If i user your idea of adding the GraphDisplay usercontrol in Mainwindow.xaml , How would i pass the selected checkboxes string variable to the display the graph of the selcted checkboxes only ? Could you please write a pseudocode to follow ?

Comment: You can specify the DataContext in the declaring xaml

Comment: Or you create a Dependency Property on your GraphDisplay and bind that to your VM property

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you use some MVVM framework for this if you really want to save you a lot of time and follow best practices.

However if you can't use any of these frameworks, due to design restrictions, then you need to implement your own solution for **view model interactions**.

I'd also recommend you to read about the [Interaction Request Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=PandP.40).aspx#sec10) on the Prism's docs. Although the content here is equally applicable to any framework (or even when you implement your own solution).

> As per the docs, to implement notifications and interactions in a MVVM
>   application while keeping a clean separation of concerns can be a very
>   tricky thing to do.

Thing is that is the view model the responsible for initiating an interaction with the user and to get and process the response, while the view is responsible for present the interaction UI to the user using whatever presentation technology is being used in the app.

> Two main common approaches:

**Using an interaction service:**
Here the view model uses a service implementation in order to initiate interactions with the user so here the viewmodel has a dependency to the `IInteractionService` via DI/IoC.

**Using Interaction Request Objects**
Here the viewmodel makes interaction requests directly to view using interaction objects coupled with a behavior in the view.

This is the recommended approach and the way it's implemented in Prism for instance. It's a simple, yet very powerful and it correctly keeps a clean separation of concerns.

There is a lot more in the docs, so if you can't use any of these great framework out there, I'd again strongly recommend you to plan carefully how'd you go to implement your solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, You mean i should use IInteractionService  interface of PRISM. But i am not using PRISM.

Comment: What I mean is that you should use a framework because it can get ugly, but if you can't then you should implement any of those two approaches - the one you like the most - of interaction patterns in your solution.